# Knob doesn't trigger the circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, geometry, cycle

we are trying to set up the percentage of ur circle with a jQuery file. 
If we try to use the function nothing happends....

```html
 <div class="cycle">
  <input type="text" value=0 class="itemcycle"/>
  <input type="text" value=0 class="timecycle"/>
    <script>
      $(".itemcycle").knob({ min: 0,max: 50,width: 370,height: 370,fgColor: '#ac2a29',bgColor: '#e0e0e0',thickness: '.2',readOnly: true});
      $(".timecycle").knob({ min: 0,max: 50,width: 292,height: 292,fgColor: '#00BB00',bgColor: '#eeeeee',thickness: '.05',readOnly: true});
    </script>
  </div>
```

```js
function cset(v)
{
    $('.itemcycle')
        .val(v)
        .trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging in Dev Tools to get any error messages that might be thrown?

Comment: Nope, we dont have any error messages.